# Do the following computations on 4-bit unsigned numbers result in overflow?

Tags: binary, numbers, overflow, unsigned

The answer key says that 0010 - 1001 results in overflow. If numbers are unsigned, the expression is 2 - 9, which equals -7. Overflow definition: If the result of a computation cannot be represented using the allocated number of bits (e.g., 4 bits here), this computation is said to have an overflow. -7 in 2's complement notation is: 1001, that is it can be represented using the given 4 bits. So why does 0010 - 1001 leads to overflow?

```
 0010
-1001
------
 1001
```

Comment: "If numbers are unsigned..", then Smaller - Larger = Overflow (regardless of where it lands)

Comment: Because it will not interpreted as -7 but 9 since it unsigned, so the result is invalid.